# как сделать так, чтобы изображение не "подгонялось" под размер контейнера, в котором оно находится?

Tags: html, css

логотип сайта растягивается при увеличении размеров шапки. как с этим бороться?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в зависимости от того, как именно выводится изображения

1. если в качестве `background` блока, то изменением свойства `background-size`
2. если в качестве изображения `<img>`, то изменением свойств `width` и `height` - если они относительные (например: `width: 50%`), то выставлением абсолютных значений (например, `width: 300px`)

Comment: точнее так: картинка растягивается, если использовать display:flex